# Node.js on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I want to have Node.js running on a RPi and a browser running on the same RPI at the time and the two talking to each other. I know I can do this over a network with a separate client machine - but I want to control the RPi I/O pins with the browser running in the RPi. Is this possible?

Comment: Provided that there's a GPIO library for Node.js, this should be possible. I've done similar, using a browser pointed to localhost, and a Python backend to control the I/O pins. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask, unless you have a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [pi-gpio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pi-gpio) npm package on Node.js. Your browser then controls the GPIO pins thru Node.js.